# 'management.endpoints.web.exposure.include' is an unknown property

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to implement Spring Actuator for the first time and when I'm trying to enable all endpoints in **application.properties** it shows **'management.endpoints.web.exposure.include' is an unknown property**. And the response to the request is:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-08-26T06:07:47.120Z",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/actuator/health"
}
```

Other than this I've just included

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in pom.xml and nothing else. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Can you share the spring boot version? This property path has been changed from 1.x to 2.x . `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include` this is a 2.x configuration.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing it out. My Spring-Boot version is 1.X

Answer (score 1):

Did you also add spring web as a dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, I did. I added:

Comment: try mvn clean install?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error,  I added the actuator dependency and built my project once, so the error disappeared.

> actuator version is 2.7.2

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```